# Action Script 3.0 gotoAndStop() not sync with its content

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, frame

i have a movieClip, which has 3 frames. when i call `mc.init();` the mc movieClip should check with the current language and go to the specific frame. 
E.g. current lang is 'tw', the trace correctly returns 2. However, the on screen display is the content of frame 1. and i can still trace a movieClip inside frame 1.

Can anyone tell me the reason of the issue??

## mc (movieClip)

```
function changeLanguage(){
if (currentLang =='en'){
gotoAndStop(1);
}else if (currentLang=='tw'){
gotoAndStop(2);
}else if (currentLang=='fr'){
gotoAndStop(3);
}

trace(this.currentFrame);

}

function init(){
changeLanguage();
}
```

## main.as

```
mc.init();
```

## added 2:23am 21Jun2012

i found that it can gotoAndStop(3) without any problem, only when from frame2 to frame1 has the problem.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your problem is... Is your problem that you use gotoAndStop, but the animation is still playing?

Comment: The problem is, although i can trace the frame number 2, it is still showing the content of frame 1

Comment: are you definitely targeting the right movieclip?

Comment: Hi TheSHEEEP, no. i have stop(); in each frame of the movieClip. the problem is that, the gotoAndStop updated the frame number, but the content of the movieClip still stays at frame 1.

Comment: To Tom: Yes. i am quite sure. i added a textfield inside each frame,.e.g. 1111,2222,3333 and i tried to trace it right after the gotoAndStop. it returns 1111

Comment: accessing things on the timeline from code can be tricky, it doesn't like it unless the actionscript is on the same frame, or what you are trying to access exists on all frames